# Mapcache: ValueError: unsupported format character 'j' (0x6a) at index 55

Tags: wms, bing-maps, mapcache

For my first attempt at using Mapcache, I wish to create a caching proxy of Bing Maps, serving a WMS. I started 'mapproxy-util serve-develop' with the following .yaml configuration, assembled from studying the documentation :

```
services:
  wms:
    md:
      abstract: ''
      title: Microsoft Bing orbital imagery caching proxy
    srs: ['EPSG:3857']

layers:
-   name: Bing_imagery_layer
    title: WMS layer from Microsoft Bing orbital imagery tiles
    sources: [Bing_imagery_cache]

caches:
  Bing_imagery_cache:
    grids: [GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR]
    sources: [Microsoft_Bing_imagery]
    cache:
      type: file
      directory: /home/jm/projects/mapproxy/cache
      directory_layout: tms
    
sources:
  Microsoft_Bing_imagery:
    type: tile
    grid: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    url: http://ecn.t2.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a%(quadkey).jpeg?g=1&mkt=en-US
```

And here is the observed behaviour:

```
$ mapproxy-util serve-develop Bing_orbital_imagery_cache_WMS.yaml
[2016-05-24 00:17:50,048] mapproxy.config - INFO - reading: /home/jm/projects/mapproxy/mymapproxy/Bing_orbital_imagery_cache_WMS.yaml
[info]  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[info]  * Restarting with reloader
[2016-05-24 00:17:50,771] mapproxy.config - INFO - reading: /home/jm/projects/mapproxy/mymapproxy/Bing_orbital_imagery_cache_WMS.yaml
[2016-05-24 00:17:54,457] mapproxy.wsgiapp - CRITICAL - fatal error in wms for /wms?FORMAT=image/jpeg&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=Bing_imagery_layer&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:3857&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&BBOX=-1232777.2003892,1692622.3427892,-1227885.2307892,1697514.3123892
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jm/projects/mapproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/wsgiapp.py", line 189, in __call__
    resp = self.handlers[handler_name].handle(req)
  File "/home/jm/projects/mapproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/service/ows.py", line 38, in handle
    return self.services[service].handle(req)
  File "/home/jm/projects/mapproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/service/base.py", line 30, in handle
    return handler(parsed_req)
  File "/home/jm/projects/mapproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/service/wms.py", line 131, in map
    renderer.render(merger)
  File "/home/jm/projects/mapproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/service/wms.py", line 530, in render
    layer_merger)
  File "/home/jm/projects/mapproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/service/wms.py", line 567, in _render_capture_source_errors
    raise ex[1]
ValueError: unsupported format character 'j' (0x6a) at index 55
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jm/projects/mapproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/wsgiapp.py", line 189, in __call__
    resp = self.handlers[handler_name].handle(req)
  File "/home/jm/projects/mapproxy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/service/ows.py", line 38, in handle
```

In the URL passed to Mapcache, the only occurrence of the letter "j" mentioned in the error message is in "FORMAT=image/jpeg" - so I thought maybe the forward slash must be encoded as %2F but trying that yielded the same behavior.

Even stranger, I tried passing "FORMAT=image/png" so that the entire URL contains no occurrence of the letter "j" and I got exactly the same result: "ValueError: unsupported format character 'j' (0x6a) at index 55"

Can you suggest a new hypothesis?

From the lack of Google results for "unsupported format character" "mapcache" it seems that I managed to err in exotic ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was in my template variable syntax... And the letter "j" put me on its trail ! In the configuration,

```
url: http://ecn.t2.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a%(quadkey).jpeg?g=1&mkt=en-US
```

is wrong and must be

```
url: http://ecn.t2.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a%(quadkey)s.jpeg?g=1&mkt=en-US
```

Note the "s" character after the closing parenthesis - it is part of the template variable syntax, [as explained in the documentation](http://mapproxy.org/docs/latest/sources.html?highlight=variables#tiles)

It works !